# Display current posts category Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

On my front-page.php I have a custom loop displaying all posts. I loop through them and display the featured image and title. I also want to add the category that the post is in but seem to be hitting a brick wall! 
It's probably an easy fix but any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code.

```
    <? $posts = get_posts(); 
    foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

        <? global $post; $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);?>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div <?php post_class( 'category-wrapper' ); ?>>
                <div class="post-image">
                    <? if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <p class="title"><? the_title(); ?></p>
                    <p class="cat-title"><?= $categories['cat_name']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <? endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Here's a wild guess. I believe `$categories` is accessed through `->`. Haven't done wordpress in a while.

Comment: I tired it with $categories->cat_name and nothing. I know it's something simple but can't figure it out. Maybe a fresh head tomorrow will solve the problem.

Comment: Can you `var_dump` the `$categories` and see if it's in there? Also, you have a `<?= $categories['cat_name']; ?>` equal sign at the front. Might want to remove that.

Comment: The function [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/#return) returns an array of object, so you need also run a `foreach` loop.

Comment: when I dump it the cat_name is there yeah. The <?= is a short php tag for <?php echo 

@bhelmet Looks like thats the reason! How do I pull out just the current post cat name though as i'm already in one foreach. So that will get every cat name for every post.

Comment: @craigb88 Glad you found the answer. Haven't been to this side of the world in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example:

```
<? $posts = get_posts(); 
foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <? global $post; $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);?>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div <?php post_class( 'category-wrapper' ); ?>>
            <div class="post-image">
                <? if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="post-content">
                <p class="title"><? the_title(); ?></p>
                <? foreach( $categories as $category ): ?>
                    <p class="cat-title"><?= $category->cat_name; ?></p>
                <? endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<? endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Of course it is! I was thinking it would return every category. Thank You.